# How do i use Qhull options for LinearNDInterpolator in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, qhull

I am trying to compute an interpolation with:

```
import scipy.interpolate as si

import scipy

f = si.LinearNDInterpolator(Q, h)
```

**It gives me the following error**:

```
QhullError: qhull precision warning: 
The initial hull is narrow (cosine of min. angle is 1.0000000000000000).
Is the input lower dimensional (e.g., on a plane in 3-d)?  Qhull may
produce a wide facet.  Options 'QbB' (scale to unit box) or 'Qbb' (scale
last coordinate) may remove this warning.  Use 'Pp' to skip this warning.
```

**My question is** : ***How do i change the Option to QbB***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`LinearNDInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html) has the keyword `rescale`, which could be helpful.

Regarding the Qhull options, you can specify them when you actually perform the triangulation, through [`scipy.spatial.Delaunay`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html). Then, you can provide the triangulation object to `LinearNDInterpolator`.